# NvApiWrapper: Как я могу найти информацию о других "ID" для GPU Memory(RAM) Type? (C#)

Tags: c#, видео

Как я могу найти информацию о других **"ID"** для **GPUMemoryType?** (C#)

P.S.: Ниже то что я уже имею, но нужно больше

```
    namespace NvAPIWrapper.Native.GPU
{
    public enum GPUMemoryType : uint
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        SDRAM = 1,
        DDR1 = 2,
        DDR2 = 3,
        GDDR2 = 4,
        GDDR3 = 5,
        GDDR4 = 6,
        DDR3 = 7,
        GDDR5 = 8,
        LPDDR2 = 9,
        GDDR5X = 10
    }
}
```

Comment: судя по всему, их пока больше нет https://github.com/falahati/NvAPIWrapper/blob/8d4991159b026277562d09ec2df0b1eaa5ed2331/NvAPIWrapper/Native/GPU/GPUMemoryType.cs

Comment: @KoVadim [GDDR6](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR6)

Comment: легкий гуглинг не показал таких констант в оффициальной доке, единственное, что эта функция не является оффициальной. Но думаю, самое простое решение - подождать, пока кто то купит карту с такой памятью и там запустим приложение.

Comment: @KoVadim Есть, у меня GDDR6, с айди 14, и я добавил ее туда, но хотелось-бы видеть все возможные "индетификаторы" у типов памяти видеокарты

Comment: думаю, это Вам в NVidia нужно писать. Но в официальной доке я такого не нашел.